# which data type is used to store big statements

Tags: asp.net

I create a online exam web application in asp.net. but when I update a question more than 250 characters then it show a error "String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated  ".
What I do to store this data ?

Comment: What kind of DB are you using? How did you create the table? We need that info to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because the field is not big enough to hold your data. so if you are using SQL, just update the type for that field in table (ex:question or answer) to be :

```
NVARCHAR(MAX)
```